# Eqatec profiler in ASP.NET 4.0 not reading my web.config

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, profiling, eqatec

Ok, maybe I'm skipping a step here, but I swear I had Eqatec profiling things just fine in ASP.NET 2.0.

We upgraded our solution to ASP.NET 4, it works fine. Then I went through the typical steps:

- Built the solution in VS 2010
- Ran Eqatec and pointed it at the apps bin folder
- pick my 3 DLLs
- Click build, I have the output dir set to $(AppData) so it just adds the files to apps bin dir
- ran webdev.webserver40.exe with the port and the path
- navigate firefox to the website on my local machine

But now it's throwing weird errors saying that things in the machine level web.config can't be found. I dropped a copy of the web.config into the bin directory, and then it just complains about some of the tags in that file.

Is there an extra step I need to take here to make this work?

EDIT: A guy suggested that it may be a 64-bit issue. We run our app in 64 but, Equatec runs in 32 bit. Could that be a factor?

Comment: What is throwing the weird errors - the profiler or the webserver? And what errors? What does your web.config look like? There should be no special steps needed for ASP.NET 4.

Comment: It complains that a connection string is missing from the web.config, but it's listing the machine level config file, and it shows the connectionstring in the error.

Comment: Please elaborate. "What" complains - the webserver or profiler? If it's the profiler then you can enable more run-step tracing in Tools > Troubleshooting and maybe see why it's locating the wrong config-file, if that's truly what's going on. You're also welcome to mail that output to support@eqatec.com.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, turns out I'm just an idiot. When you fire up cassini via the WebDev exe, you're not supposed to point it at the bin folder. You point it at the project folder itself, the root of the web app. I guess this had noting to do with eqatec after all.

@Richard Flamsholt thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: Well, the answer "you're probably just an idiot" wouldn't have won me many stackoverflow-points, I reckon :-) I'm glad you got it solved. But it would be nice if the profiler could just fire up Cassini automatically for ASP.NET apps, like it can for Silverlight apps.

Comment: It would be even better if they would just integrate a good profiler into visual studio.

Comment: Visual Studio already has a profiler, but only in Premium and Ultimate versions. Premium is listed at $5,469.